# Is SMS Blackout inherited by other BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I have an SMS Blackout Window set and active in my parent-Business Unit. Is it automatically inherited by all child-BU or should I set up new SMS Blackout window for every one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular scenario, Blackout window seems to only impact on the business unit where it is enabled.

To confirm, I had tested the use case by enabling the blackout window on the parent business unit and doing an SMS send in a child BU. As a result, the SMS was successfully sent from the child BU, so it can be affirmed that the blackout window does not inherit from parent to child BU if enabled.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_send_blackouts.htm&type=5